# Faster Indexing of 3D NumPy Array From np.argpartition Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large 3D NumPy array:

```
x = np.random.rand(1_000_000_000).reshape(500, 1000, 2000)
```

And for each of the 500 2D arrays, I need to keep only the largest 800 elements within each column of each 2D array. To avoid costly sorting, I decided to use `np.argpartition`:

```
k = 800
idx = np.argpartition(x, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]
result = x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None, None], idx, np.arange(x.shape[2])]
```

While `np.argpartition` is reasonably fast, using `idx` to index back into `x` is really slow. Is there a faster (and memory efficient) way to perform this indexing?

Note that the results do not need to be in ascending sorted order. They just need to be the top 800

Comment: So `result` is (500,800,2000), a copy, not a `view`.

Comment: Yes, and I will then need to compute something (like stddev along axis=1) for each 2D array in `result` but generating `result` is super slow. Is there any alternative? Can I avoid a copy?

Comment: I tried your approach and the sort approach `out1 = np.sort(x, axis=1)[:,-k:]`, the two results are not the same.

Comment: @QuangHoang The results may not look the same because my results are not sorted (I don’t need the results to be sorted for, say, computing stddev as in my comment above). I only want 800 largest in each column for each 2D array but order does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cutting the size by 10 to fit my memory, here are times for the various steps:

Creationg:

```
In [65]: timeit x = np.random.rand(1_000_000_00).reshape(500, 1000, 200)
1.89 s ± 82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [66]: x = np.random.rand(1_000_000_00).reshape(500, 1000, 200)
In [67]: k=800
```

sort:

```
In [68]: idx = np.argpartition(x, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]
In [69]: timeit idx = np.argpartition(x, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]

2.52 s ± 292 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

the indexing:

```
In [70]: result = x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None, None], idx, np.arange(x.shape[2])]
In [71]: timeit result = x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None, None], idx, np.arange(x.shape[2])]
The slowest run took 4.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
2.6 s ± 1.87 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

All three steps take about the same time.  I don't see anything unusual about the last indexing.  This .8 GB.

A simple copy, without indexing is nearly 1 sec.

```
In [75]: timeit x.copy()
980 ms ± 231 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and full copy with advanced indexing:

```
In [77]: timeit x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None, None], np.arange(x.shape[1])[:,
    ...: None], np.arange(x.shape[2])]
1.47 s ± 37.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

trying the `idx` again:

```
In [78]: timeit result = x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None, None], idx, np.arange(x.shape[2])]
1.71 s ± 42.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Keep in mind that when the operations start using nearly all the memory, and/or start requiring swapping and special memory requests to the OS, timings can really go to pot.

### edit

You don't need the two step process.  Just use `partition`:

out = np.partition(x, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]

This is the same as `result`, and takes the same time as the `idx` step.